# Getting (non-HTTP) Client IP with load-balancer

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, load-balancing

Say I want to run something like the nyan cat telnet server (http://miku.acm.uiuc.edu/) and I need to handle 10,000 concurrent connections total. I have 10 servers in addition to a load balancer. Each server can handle 1,000 concurrent connections, and I want to put a load balancer in front of it to randomly divide the traffic to the 10 servers.

From what I've read, it's fairly simple for a load balancer to pass an HTTP request (along with the client IP) to the backend server, perhaps with FastCGI or with an X- header.

What would be the simplest way for the load balancer to pass the client IP to the backend server in this case with a simple TCP server? Would a hardware load balancer be needed, or are there ways to do this simply through software?

In other words, is there a uniform way to pass client IP when load balancing for non-HTTP stuff? The same way Google gets client IP when they load-balances Google Talk XMPP server or their Gmail IMAP server

This isn't for anything in specific; I'm just curious about if and how it can be done. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way would be for the load balancer to make itself completely invisible and pass the connection on with the source and destination IP address unmolested. For this to work, the same IP address must be assigned (as a loopback address, not to a physical interface) to all 10 servers and that would be the IP address the clients connect to. Internet traffic to that IP address has to go to the load balancer. The load balancer must be the default gateway for the servers.